# Can Google Flutter target iOS and Android in one app

Tags: ionic-framework, flutter

In Ionic I can build one app and at runtime Ionic choose the right skin Cupertino or Android.

Can Flutter do the same? I have read the documentation but I can't see any wrappers around the Android and Cupertino widgets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create separate iOs and Android "looks", you can use a plugin like this one:

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_platform_widgets#-readme-tab-

You have full control over which parts of your UI should be platform-specific, and which parts you want to keep uniform. For example, you can create your own custom button instead of using Cupertino button on iOs and RaisedButton on Android, but you may want to use different TextField widgets on iOs and Android.

Answer (score 0):

It does and it does not, some widgets behave differently out of the box depending on the platform. Like the `ScrollView`, which bounces on iOS and creates a wave like overlay on Android.

But for the real native experience you have to create your own widgets that build either Material or Cupertino UI.

Example:

```
...
Widget _customButton() {
    return Platform.isIOS
        ? CupertinoButton(
            child: Text('Tap me'),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        : RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Tap me'),
            onPressed: () {},
          );
  }
...
```